# can i use email, profile in google oauth2 scope after google plus shut down

Tags: google-oauth

I use google oauth2 for website login.
I read the document but still cannot figure out whether can I use "email" / "profile" after Google plus shutdown.

Here is oauth2 scope api.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes?hl=zh_TW .

It mention "email" / "profile" / "openid" in the Google Sign-In
 section.
However , I log in my Google API Console and I saw the scope endpoint is the same as google plus.

For "profile", both endpoints are https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
(Sorry for the Chinese snapshot)

[image]

I really confused which API would shut down by Google plus.
As far I know, the google api with "plus" would be shut down without doubt.
But anything other would be affected also ?
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to migrate from Google+ to [Google Sign-in](https://accounts.google.com/).

Use endpoints that Google lists as supported. You can find that list [here](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration).

The scopes `profile`, `email` and `openid` are listed as supported under Google Sign-In. Here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in) to the various scopes.

Refer to this [Google+ document](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) to learn exactly what is being shutdown.